# JAXB inheritance + element rename

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I have the following construction:

```
@XMLTransient
public abstract class Foo {
   protected String name;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"name"})
public class BarX extends Foo {

   public String getXThing() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setXThing(String thing) {
      name = thing;
   }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"name"})
public class BarY extends Foo {

   public String getYBlah() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setYBlah(String blah) {
      name = blah;
   }
}
```

Within the XML I need for BarX instead of `name` the tag `thing` and for BarY I would like to have `blah` instead of `name`. Is it possible and how I can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (you were already pretty close):

**Foo**

```
package forum11340316;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlTransient
public abstract class Foo {
   protected String name;
}
```

**BarX**

```
package forum11340316;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"XThing"})
public class BarX extends Foo {

   @XmlElement(name="thing")
   public String getXThing() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setXThing(String thing) {
      name = thing;
   }

}
```

**BarY**

```
package forum11340316;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"YBlah"})
public class BarY extends Foo {

   @XmlElement(name="blah")
   public String getYBlah() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setYBlah(String blah) {
      name = blah;
   }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11340316;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BarX.class, BarY.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        BarX barX = new BarX();
        barX.setXThing("XThing");
        marshaller.marshal(barX, System.out);

        BarY barY = new BarY();
        barY.setYBlah("YBlah");
        marshaller.marshal(barY, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<barX>
    <thing>XThing</thing>
</barX>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<barY>
    <blah>YBlah</blah>
</barY>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html